# Is there a good SharePoint 2010 Page Profiling tool about?

Tags: performance, profiling

If I want to measure how long it takes for my browser to render a page, requests, scripts, the lot, in ie9, what's a good tool for that?

The idea being is that I have a very heavy page which I want to speed up and it would be nice to get an idea how much it's been improved.

Answer (score 8):

There's two very simple ways:

1. Use the Developer Dashboard feature in SharePoint 2010 - it allows you to see where the server spends time rendering your page
2. Use the IE9 Network profiler (F12 in IE9 and the Network profiler tab)

Comment: Don't really care about the server, scope for improvement means dealing with the infrastructure team!

I had a look at the profiler but thought it was for JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried Fiddler? I think it would serve your purposes really well.
http://www.getfiddler.com
You could also enable the SharePoint Developer Dashboard to see loadtimes etc on a page. To enable it see use:

```
$service = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$addsetting =$service.DeveloperDashboardSettings
$addsetting.DisplayLevel = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::On
$addsetting.Update()
```

in Powershell.

Comment: I thought about fiddler but a lot of the waiting seems to be in script.

Answer (score 0):

A rather crude (but nonetheless useful) technique I've used in the past to help isolate browser processing time issues from server side processing times is to stick a couple of pieces of javascript into the top and bottom of the page.

For example, if you can edit your masterpage, at the very top, just inside the HEAD tag, you could put the following.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var xStart = (new Date()).getTime();
</script>
```

Then and the very bottom of the masterpage, just before the closing BODY tag, add

```
<script language="javascript">

   function ShowPageTimer() {
      var xEnd = (new Date()).getTime() - xStart;
      alert("Time to load in browser (ms):" + xEnd);
   }
   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ShowPageTimer");

</script>
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like this but it would probably be better to use events out of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The tools which can help on this matter are :

- Developer Dashboard
- Fiddler\HttpWatch
- Visual Round Trip Analyzer

For details , You can check : http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/25/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-tools-techniques/